# Table border-bottom at rows

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I try to put a border-bottom at the table-rows but they don't show up. Why is that?

http://www.mysecretathens.gr/Sera/dates.html

I think my code is pretty simple putting a class to ther tr element.

```
<tr class="line">

table tr.line {border-bottom: 1px solid #B4B5B0;}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
tr.line td{ 
border-bottom: 1px solid #B4B5B0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put borders on tr elements. You have to put them on td

Change your style to:

tr.line td{ border-bottom: 1px solid #B4B5B0;}

Answer (score 1):

Add "border-collapse: collapse" style to your table element and that should bring up the row borders

Answer (score 0):

Do it on the table cells, it works for all browsers.

`table tr.line td {border-bottom: 1px solid #B4B5B0;}`

Answer (score 0):

if you have a single table on the page, you may try;

```
td{
  border-bottom: solid 1px #B4B5B0;
}
```

or if you have multiple tables, use class, like;

```
.your_table_class td{
  border-bottom: solid 1px #B4B5B0;
}
```